# Facebook registration

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa-touch, twitter

I need to add the 'Share' on Facebook and Twitter buttons to my iPhone app. Before I get any further, do I have to go register on Facebook Developers, under Mobile Apps, in order to get an App ID (and then implement the Single Sign On)? How about Twitter?

Comment: Have you tried to read any facebook app development manual?

Answer (score 6):

First of all you need to register your app in facebook and twitter under development

For twitter go to this  http://dev.twitter.com and for the facebook go to this  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/

when you register your mobile app you will get api key go to http://www.getsharekit.com . here is the open source api for share item (text, image , file , link ) to share on facebook , twitter and many more.

just check it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do need to register with Facebook and be issued an App ID.  Without this, you won't be able to do very much at all with their API.  All the information you will need is available here:

https://developers.facebook.com/

...as well as the facilities to create your app and App ID.

Answer (score 0):

If you are intending to use Facebook and Twitter official SDK, you will have to get ID from their respective developer console. For Facebook the official SDK can be downloaded [here](https://developers.facebook.com/ios/) and for twitter the official SDK is [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios).

Updated : From iOS 6 onwards, you can use Apple's own [Social Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012233) to share with Facebook and Twitter.